# LiveAgent Chat + Lightning Out throws "$Lightning.use() already invoked with application"

Tags: lightning-web-components, liveagent, lightning-out

When attempting to embed LiveAgent Chat on a public facing page that also contains a lightning out packaged aura/LWC, lightning.out.js throws `$Lightning.use() already invoked with application: c:appname` and the chat component fails to start.

I'm new to LiveAgent, but taking the error at its word, I am assuming that means that it uses the same lightning out container that the aura/LWC is using?

Is there some kind of workaround for packaging a custom LWC along with the chat container into a single app, or somehow including the LWC in the existing chat package, or is this just an expected, by design incompatibility?

Answer (score 1):

we managed to get this to work by using the same app as the live chat:

```
$Lightning.use("embeddedService:sidebarApp", function()
```

Comment: how did you handle the styling for the scheduler after you added that update? When we did it, the styling got messed up.